# $\omega$ a closed 2-form and $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \omega \ne 0$ on a compact orientable smooth $2n$-manifold w/o boundary, $M$, then $H^2(M) \ne 0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, exterior-algebra, de-rham-cohomology

> Suppose $M$ is a compact orientable smooth $2n$-manifold without boundary, and let $\omega$ be a closed $2$-form such that $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \omega_p \ne 0$ at every point $p$. Show that $H^2_{dR}(M) \ne 0$.

That is, $(M, \omega)$ is a symplectic manifold.

I'm not sure what to try with this. Any ideas on how to show this?

Comment: Fyi, this is telling you something important about symplectic manifolds: their second cohomology can’t vanish.

Comment: what is $\Lambda_{i=1}^n$ do you mean $\Lambda^n$ ?

Comment: $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n \omega =\omega^n=\omega \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega$, wedges $n$ times.

Comment: Be careful!  Do you want $\omega^n\neq 0$ happening in $\Omega^{2n}(M)$ or in $H^{2n}(M)$?  The latter is easy, the former is not true.

Comment: @user10354138 I think your comment is incorrect; the definition of a symplectic form is a closed 2-form so that $\omega^n$ is pointwise nonzero. Such 2-forms are popular, both at conferences and at parties.

Comment: Please  be careful with your notation. You mean to say that $\omega^n$ is *nowhere* $0$, I believe, not that it is not identically $0$.

Comment: @MikeMiller So by your interpretation of $\omega^n\neq 0$ in $\Omega^{2n}(M)$, you are saying the two $2$-forms $\cos(x^1)\,\mathrm{d}x^{12}$ and $0$ are equal in $\Omega^2(\mathbb{T}^2)$?

Comment: I edited the OP's post to make it clear we are interested in the symplectic condition, $\omega^n_p \neq 0$ at every point $p$. If I have misinterpreted the intent, feel free to roll it back, but I remark that it is very easy to construct an exact 2-form on any $2n$-manifold with $\omega^n_p \neq 0$ at any given point but so that $\omega^n$ is not globally nonzero (this is the contradiction), and hence there is nothing to say about the problem.

Comment: I have not studied symplectic forms yet. So I'm not sure about all the symplectic terminology.

Answer (score 3):

If the second de Rham cohomology were trivial, $\omega$ would be $d\alpha$ for some 1-form $\alpha$.

Then use the non-boundary condition and Stokes via

$$\int_M\omega^n=\int_Md(\alpha\wedge\omega^{n-1})=\int_{\partial M}\cdots=\cdots$$

to derive a contradiction with $\omega^n\neq0$.

Comment: How is $\omega^n= d(\alpha \wedge \omega^{n-1})$? I'm getting $$d(\alpha \wedge \omega^{n-1})=d\alpha \wedge \omega^{n-1} -\alpha \wedge d\omega^{n-1}=\omega^n-\alpha \wedge d\omega^{n-1}.$$

Comment: @AlJebr Show that if a form $\omega$ is closed, so is $\omega^k$ for all $k$, by showing that the wedge product of any two closed forms is closed.

Comment: Why is $\int_M \omega^n =0$ a contradiction?

Comment: @AlJebr What do you know about $\omega^n$?

Comment: @MikeMiller You only know that there is a point $p\in M$ such that $\omega^n(p)\neq 0$.  You are not given this for all $p\in M$ in the question statement by one of the possible interpretation of $\bigwedge_{i=1}^n\omega$.

Comment: As I indicated in my comments above, @user10354138, I believe you are wrong here. You are misinterpreting the original statement.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long comment. To emphasize that you must interpret the hypothesis as being that $\omega^n (p) \ne 0$ for all $p\in M$, let me give a counterexample with the other interpretation (@user10354138). Let $M=S^4\times S^4$, with obvious projection maps $\pi_i$, $i=1,2$, to the $i$th factor. Choose any nonzero exact $2$-form $\eta$ on $S^4$ with the property that $\eta^2 = \eta\wedge\eta$ is not identically $0$. For example, take a compactly-supported exact $2$-form on $\Bbb R^4$, which extends naturally to be a form on $S^4$. [To be explicit, take $\rho_1$ to be a smooth  function that is $1$ on the unit ball in $\Bbb R^3$ and $0$ outside the ball of radius $2$, and let $\rho_2$ be $1$ on the ball of radius $1$ centered at $(1,0,0,0)$ and $0$ outside the ball of radius $2$ centered at that point. Let $\eta = d(\rho_1\,dx-\rho_2\,dy)$. Note that $\eta^2 = d\rho_1\wedge d\rho_2\wedge dx\wedge dy$ will be nonzero at certain points of the intersection of the two balls of radius $2$.] Now let $\omega = \pi_1^*\eta + \pi_2^*\eta$. Then $\omega^4 = 6\pi_1^*(\eta^2)\wedge\pi_2^*(\eta^2)$ will be not identically zero on $S^4\times S^4$, and yet $H^2(S^4\times S^4) = 0$.